# TinyMCE buttons not showing

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-3

I have added indent and outdent buttons to the tiny MCE configuration as follows:

tinyMCE.init({
    // General options
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "advanced",
    editor_selector : cl2,
    skin : "o2k7",
    plugins : "advimage,advlink,spellchecker,inlinepopups,contextmenu,paste,noneditable,mergefields",
    spellchecker_languages : "+English=en",
    // Theme options
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,code,removeformat,|,spellchecker",        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,bullist,numlist,|,link,unlink,image,hr,|,cut,copy,paste,pasteword,|**,indent,outdent,|**,undo,redo",        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
    theme_advanced_path : false,
    theme_advanced_resizing : true,        cleanup_on_startup : false,
    convert_fonts_to_spans : false,
    convert_newlines_to_brs : false,
    inline_styles : false,
    remove_linebreaks : true,
    remove_trailing_nbsp : true,
    trim_span_elements : false,
    content_css : "htmlArea/styles/client.css"
    });
    }

Investigating the html generated reveals that no table cell containing the indent/outdent links exists. Have checked tinyMCE's image directory and the relevant images for the buttons exist. Is there another configuration setting which needs to be changed?

Version is 3.5.8.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue caused by adding indent outdent config options to wrong instantiation of editor on page.

Another one was located, once added there appeared appeared as normal.